# How to call parametrized method in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I have such  a method:

```
private static <T extends HomerMessage> HomerMessage postRequest(String path, HomerMessage json) throws IOException, HomerDoh
{
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, toJson(json));
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url("http://" + path).post(body).build();

    String response = new OkHttpClient().newCall(request).execute().body().string();
    System.out.println(response);
    JsonNode responseNode = new ObjectMapper().readValue(response, JsonNode.class);
    if(!"200".equals(responseNode.get("status")))
    {
        throw readData(response, new TypeReference<HomerDoh>() {});
    }
    return readData(response, new TypeReference<T>() {});
}

private static <T> T readData(String is, TypeReference<T> ref) throws IOException
{
    return mapper.readValue(is, ref);
}
```

All works fine, but I could not figure out how to call it...
I have tried:

```
     AuthResponse ar = HomerClient.postRequest(url + "/api/v1/session", auth);
```

The last expression does not compile.

How to call parametrized method in Java?

AuthResponse extends HomerMessage

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: BTW, that method is completely broken; it needs to take a `TypeReference` as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't compile because it's not returning an `AuthResponse`: it is returning a `HomerMessage`.

You can make the return type `AuthResponse` if you change the return type of the method to:

```
private static <T extends HomerMessage> T postRequest(
    String path, HomerMessage json, TypeReference<T> typeRef)
        throws IOException, HomerDoh
```

which is the return type of your only normally-completing code path.

---

As noted by @SLaks, you can't use `TypeReference` with generics:

```
new TypeReference<T>() {}
```

Because of erasure, this will be equivalent at runtime to:

```
new TypeReference<Object>() {}
```

which is almost certainly not what you want - otherwise you could just have used that, and not had an issue calling the generic method in the first place.

You need to actually pass in the concrete `TypeReference` as a parameter:

```
private static <T extends HomerMessage> T postRequest(
    String path, HomerMessage json, TypeReference<T> typeRef)
        throws IOException, HomerDoh
```

then you can call this simply as:

```
AuthResponse response = postRequest(
    url + "/api/v1/session", auth,
    new TypeReference<AuthResponse>() {});
```

and the type `T` is inferred from the third parameter.

Comment: You should also replace `HomerDoh` with `T` in the `throws` clause of the `postRequest` method and use `typeRef` when calling `throw readData(response, typeRef)`. Otherwise, your code won't compile.

Comment: @RZet are you sure? Looks OK to me.

Comment: Pretty sure you will get `'Unhandled exception type T'` compilation error. This is the type `readData()` method returns.

Comment: @RZet nope. Try it. The *return type* and *thrown types* are quite separate.

Comment: This is what I get in a sample code I created. Have you actually coded it yourself or replied by heart?

Comment: Yes, I agree. I overlooked that the original argument passed to the `readData` method is `'new TypeReference<HomerDoh>() {}'` rather than the argument of the `postRequest` method.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide the name of the class, where the `static` method is defined:

```
Exception ar = SomeClass.<Exception>getException();
```

Answer (score 1):

The expression `Exception ar = <Exception>getException();` cannot compile because the generic method parametrization idiom requires a class name (or variable name if the method wasn't static) prior to parametrization.

For instance:

```
Exception ar = MyClass.<Exception>getException();
```

For instance methods:

- `Exception ar = theObject.<Exception>getException();`
- `Exception ar = this.<Exception>getException();`